# GetX usage in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Trying to use GetX framework to implement Global state management system, but it's not getting update inside the Widget as soon as the state value updated.

Comment: Have use used GetBuilder or Obx?

Comment: share your snippet and what you tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
RxInt number = 0.obs;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Obx(() => Text(number.value.toString())),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          number.value++;
        },
        child: const Text('+1'),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```